# SQL Select for Users only in certain List of Groups

Tags: sql

I need to select a group of users that are in certain user_groups, but **only** in those user_groups.

```
User
1
2
3

Group
a
b
c

UserToGroup
1, a
1, b
1, c
2, a
2, c
3, b
3, c
```

User must **only** be in Groups a and c

```
Result
2, a
2, c
```

Group and User are both scaling tables, so excluding unwanted groups in the query is not an option.

Comment: What type and version of SQL?

Comment: Do you want users in group `a` or `c` (but no others), or in **both** `a` and `c` (but no others)?

Comment: User must be in all groups of a provided list. SQL Version: MySQL 5.5.60-0+deb7u1

Comment: You never answered what RDBMS you are using. The question still needs to be properly tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I modified the query to include other data from the user table.

If you need to get other data from `user` and/or `group`, you can use a simple `JOIN` with `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate records with something other than your select list. It should optimize pretty well. The `HAVING count(*)` relies on there not being more than one linking record in the `usertorgroup` for a `user` and `group`. If either is a concern, the query can be filtered further to eliminate those duplicates. It also needs to be passed how many groups are being searched. How are you passing this list of values to the query?

```
SELECT u.uid AS userid, u.otherstuff
FROM usr u
INNER JOIN usertogroup utg ON u.uid = utg.uid
INNER JOIN grp g ON utg.gid = g.gid
  AND g.gid IN ('a','c')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM usertogroup utg2 
    WHERE utg2.gid NOT IN ('a','c')
       AND utg2.uid = u.uid
)
GROUP BY u.uid, u.otherstuff
HAVING count(*) = 2 /* # of items in list to search. */
```

Demo:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f51dbd8a6013d9ec94120cf1ec512735
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96e2a7/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserToGroup
WHERE `user` IN (
  SELECT `user`
  FROM UserToGroup
  GROUP BY `user`
  HAVING count(distinct `group`)
     = count(distinct CASE WHEN `group` IN ('a','c') THEN `group` END )
)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19bfcfa320ca5e2afbf48a1bbb09a1a1

---

> I need distinct users. I have reduced the columns of user to easen the
>   example.

To get data from `Users` use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE `user` IN (
  SELECT `user`
  FROM UserToGroup
  GROUP BY `user`
  HAVING count(distinct `group`)
     = count(distinct CASE WHEN `group` IN ('a','c') THEN `group` END )
)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a75d024ce0c871bca6ff3062ca1bc0f

Comment: Almost there, can i have distinct result sets, so i can easily join in the user table?

Comment: Do you want to get distinct users ? Or distinct pairs: group+users ? I don't understant this requirement. I can't see the reason of joining this query to `users` table in this example, because `users` contains exactly the same users-id as in `UserToGroup` table, and nothing more.

Comment: I need distinct users. I have reduced the columns of user to easen the example.

Comment: I've added an example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want users that are only in A and C, then you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(USER_ID) AS USER_ID
FROM
    UserToGroup
HAVING
    MIN(USER_GROUP) = 'a' AND MAX(USER_GROUP) = 'c'
```

If they are in A and C and D, then that query won't work for you.

You could also try

```
SELECT 
    USER_ID
FROM
    UserToGroup
WHERE USER_GROUP = 'a' 
      AND USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM UserToGroup WHERE USER_GROUP = 'c')
```

This query gets everyone that is in 'a', and also looks in a subquery against the same table for users that are in 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try conditional aggregation in a `HAVING` clause, that checks for the counts of `'a'` and `'c'` to be exactly 1 and all others to be 0.

Assuming the column names of `usertogroup` are `user` and `group`.

```
SELECT ug1.user,
       ug1.group
       FROM usertogroup ug1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT ug2.user
                               FROM usertogroup ug2
                               GROUP BY ug2.user
                               HAVING count(CASE 
                                              WHEN ug2.group = 'a') THEN
                                                1
                                            END) = 1
                                      AND count(CASE 
                                                  WHEN ug2.group = 'c') THEN
                                                    1
                                                END) = 1
                                      AND count(CASE
                                                  WHEN ug2.group NOT IN ('a', 'c') THEN
                                                    1
                                                END) = 0) x
                       ON x.user = ug1.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want :

```
       SELECT
         CASE WHEN GROUPS IN ('a','c')
         THEN 
          USERS||'-'||GROUPS  
          ELSE
          'USER IN SOME OTHER GROUP'
            END CASE 

         FROM TABLE order by Groups ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the users that belong to exactly 2 groups and then apply the condition that these groups are `a` and `c`:

```
select u.* from UserToGroup as u 
inner join (
  select userid from UserToGroup 
  group by userid
  having count(*) = 2
) as t
on 
  t.userid = u.userid
  and
  u.groupid IN ('a', 'c')
  and 
  not exists (
    select 1 
    from UserToGroup as uu 
    where 
      uu.userid = t.userid 
      and 
      uu.groupid NOT IN ('a', 'c')
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5VQ2Dz3azLM85CaryLnm97/0)